# Use hyphen as string for regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have developed a regex in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) which checks a specific pattern in a log file..

string looks something like this :

```
05-20-2013 15:57:09.334715 [del1-dhp-26330] Read 100 entries from syslog file test
```

and my regex function is

```
\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d\d\d\d [@"+agentName+"]"+" Read 100 entries from "+flatFileLogSourceName;
```

where agent name and flatfilelogsource name will retrieve me the respective values in the string.

but am getting an error says `[x-y]` range in reverse order.. which should be because of the agent name as it contains hyphen.

so I am basically looking for a method which could escape hyphen as a string like `@` does to `\`

Comment: did you try `\-` to escape the hypen

Comment: Which part exactly is supposed to be the regex?  You should enclose it in backticks, `like so`.

Comment: isn't `String.Split()` enough?

Comment: @saravanan , i can't make any alterations in the agent name

Comment: @ShobhitMaheshwari: You will just escape the hypen in the regex not any changes in the name so that regex will not look for range and instead it will look for a hypen as a matchable character

Comment: Unrelated, but you can do `\d{4}` instead of `\d\d\d\d`.

Comment: You'll also have to escape the . as \. because . in regex means match any character

Answer (score 2):

For the error message that you recibe, I think `"[@"+agentName+"]"` should be writen as `"\[@"+agentName+"\]"` like in most regular expression flavors, although I don't know the implementation of C#.

**Quick explanation**

The square brackets forms a class, a kind of collection of valid characters for to match. Those classes can use ranges as `[0-9]` for matching numbers in decimal notation or `[0-7]` to match them in octal notation. And to match series of characters like `[a-e]` which match a, b, c, d or e. But ranges can't go in reverse order. So `[a-z]` is a valid range but `[z-a]` is not. To avoid creating a character class, you must escape the square brackets with a backslask

Answer (score 1):

\ is the regex escape character.

This should work:

```
"\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6} \["+agentName+"\] Read 100 entries from "+flatFileLogSourceName
```

**Edit:** Although seeing this sentence confuses me as to what you are actually asking for:

> where agent name and flatfilelogsource name will retrieve me the
>   respective values in the string.

If you're trying to pull data out of the regex match, this should help you: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html